# OnClick event in Javascript not taking effect

Tags: javascript

I've searched for this question and none of the other questions have a similar setup to mine. Basically, I'm following a tutorial and want to create a custom pop-up window that asks the user if they want to do an action. This pop up window has a "Yes" and a "No" button. My issue is nothing happens when either of the buttons are clicked. Here is my code, I am using brackets.

```js
    /*global alert, prompt, window, document*/
    "use strict";
    function play() {
        //text adventure game here
    }
    function CustomConfirm(){
        this.render = function() {
            var winW = window.innerWidth;
            var winH = window.innerHeight;
            var dialogoverlay = document.getElementById('dialogoverlay');
            var dialogbox = document.getElementById('dialogbox');
            dialogoverlay.style.display = "block";
            dialogoverlay.style.height = winH+"px";
            dialogbox.style.left = (winW/2) - (550 * .5) + "px";
            dialogbox.style.top = "100px";
            dialogbox.style.display = "block";
            
            document.getElementById('dialogboxhead').innerHTML = "Are you sure?";
            document.getElementById('dialogboxbody').innerHTML = "Select Yes or No...";
            document.getElementById('dialogboxfoot').innerHTML = '<button onclick="Dialog.yes()">Yes</button> <button onclick="Dialog.no()">No</button>';
        }
        this.yes = function() {
            document.getElementById('dialogbox').style.display = "none";
            document.getElementById('dialogoverlay').style.display = "none";
    
            play();
        }
        this.no = function() {
            document.getElementById('dialogbox').style.display = "none";
            document.getElementById('dialogoverlay').style.display = "none";
            alert("Goodbye!");
        }
    }
    var Confirm = new CustomConfirm();
    //play();
```

```html
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
        <head>
            <meta charset="utf-8">
            <title>JavaScript!</title>
            <link href="styles/dialog.css" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet">
            <script src="scripts/dialog.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    
        </head>
        <body>
            <h1>Zombie Apocalypse!</h1>
            <p>Directions for text adventure game here</p>

            <div id="dialogoverlay"></div>
            <div id="dialogbox">
                <div>
                    <div id="dialogboxhead"></div>
                    <div id="dialogboxbody"></div>
                    <div id="dialogboxfoot"></div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <button onclick="Confirm.render()">Play Again?</button>
        </body>
    </html>
```

Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: Where do you set the `Dialog` variable?

Comment: Are you getting any errors in the JavaScript console? Did you bother to check?

Comment: it works in code snippets, move the script tag to bottom of body

Comment: Change `dialog.` to `Confirm.` in your click handlers.

Comment: `Dialog.yes()` and `Dialog.no()` should be `Confirm.yes()` and `Confirm.no()`.

Comment: @Barmar there were no errors in the console but you are right, I was using the wrong object name. Silly mistake, thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't have a variable called Dialog. I removed your onclick and changed it to a click handler while calling `Confirm`.

```js
/*global alert, prompt, window, document*/
    "use strict";
    function play() {
        //text adventure game here
    }
    function CustomConfirm(){
        this.render = function() {
            var winW = window.innerWidth;
            var winH = window.innerHeight;
            var dialogoverlay = document.getElementById('dialogoverlay');
            var dialogbox = document.getElementById('dialogbox');
            dialogoverlay.style.display = "block";
            dialogoverlay.style.height = winH+"px";
            dialogbox.style.left = (winW/2) - (550 * .5) + "px";
            dialogbox.style.top = "100px";
            dialogbox.style.display = "block";
            
            document.getElementById('dialogboxhead').innerHTML = "Are you sure?";
            document.getElementById('dialogboxbody').innerHTML = "Select Yes or No...";
            document.getElementById('dialogboxfoot').innerHTML = '<button id="confirm-yes">Yes</button> <button id="confirm-no">No</button>';
            
            document.getElementById("confirm-yes").addEventListener("click",function(){
               Confirm.yes();
            });
    
           document.getElementById("confirm-no").addEventListener("click",function(){
             Confirm.no();
           });
        }
        this.yes = function() {
            document.getElementById('dialogbox').style.display = "none";
            document.getElementById('dialogoverlay').style.display = "none";
    
            play();
        }
        this.no = function() {
            document.getElementById('dialogbox').style.display = "none";
            document.getElementById('dialogoverlay').style.display = "none";
            alert("Goodbye!");
        }
    }
    var Confirm = new CustomConfirm();
    //play();
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
        <head>
            <meta charset="utf-8">
            <title>JavaScript!</title>
            <link href="styles/dialog.css" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet">
            <script src="scripts/dialog.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    
        </head>
        <body>
            <h1>Zombie Apocalypse!</h1>
            <p>Directions for text adventure game here</p>

            <div id="dialogoverlay"></div>
            <div id="dialogbox">
                <div>
                    <div id="dialogboxhead"></div>
                    <div id="dialogboxbody"></div>
                    <div id="dialogboxfoot"></div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <button onclick="Confirm.render()">Play Again?</button>
        </body>
    </html>
```

Comment: Yes, this was my error. I was using the Dialog object for something else but missed this change. Thanks!